# Avoiding multiple DB hits when creating / destroying habtm count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have `Gallery` and `Post` models, with a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship between the two. There isa `posts_count` column on the `Gallery` model to keep track of how many posts are in a given gallery.  It works fine, but it does more DB hits than seems necessary.

If I do something like `gallery.posts.clear` then I get a DB operation for every single post that is removed:

```
(0.3ms)  BEGIN
(0.9ms)  DELETE FROM "galleries_posts" WHERE "galleries_posts"."gallery_id" = 6 AND "galleries_posts"."post_id" IN (8, 6, 5, ..., 39, 40, 42, 41, 41, 44, 45, 47, 50, 49, 51)
(0.7ms)  UPDATE "galleries" SET "posts_count" = 54, "updated_at" = '2013-10-22 22:56:32.048238' WHERE "galleries"."id" = 6
(0.4ms)  UPDATE "galleries" SET "posts_count" = 53, "updated_at" = '2013-10-22 22:56:32.050582' WHERE "galleries"."id" = 6
(0.3ms)  UPDATE "galleries" SET "posts_count" = 52, "updated_at" = '2013-10-22 22:56:32.052247' WHERE "galleries"."id" = 6
...
(0.3ms)  UPDATE "galleries" SET "posts_count" = 3, "updated_at" = '2013-10-22 22:56:32.055607' WHERE "galleries"."id" = 6
(0.3ms)  UPDATE "galleries" SET "posts_count" = 2, "updated_at" = '2013-10-22 22:56:32.084547' WHERE "galleries"."id" = 6
(0.3ms)  UPDATE "galleries" SET "posts_count" = 1, "updated_at" = '2013-10-22 22:56:32.085752' WHERE "galleries"."id" = 6
(0.3ms)  UPDATE "galleries" SET "posts_count" = 0, "updated_at" = '2013-10-22 22:56:32.086861' WHERE "galleries"."id" = 6
(3.6ms)  COMMIT
```

This amounts to `n` DB operations to update the count, where `n` is the number of posts that are added or removed.

Is there a way to maintain the count that relies instead on an operation that just updates the gallery's `posts_count` one time, once all the posts have been added or removed?

My current methods run on `after_add`/`after_remove`:

```
class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_and_belongs_to_many :posts, after_add: :increment_posts_count, 
                                  after_remove: :decrement_posts_count
  ...
  private
    def increment_posts_count(post)
      self.increment!(:posts_count)
    end

    def decrement_posts_count(post)
      self.decrement!(:posts_count)
    end
end
```

Is there any hook to run only after the whole operation is completed?